# Terraform provider restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm encountering problems when trying to run `terraform init -upgrade`:

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: no     available releases match the given constraints >= 2.23.0, >= 2.46.0, >= 3.0.0, >=
│ 3.62.0, >= 3.69.0, ~> 3.69, >= 3.72.0, >= 4.0.0, >= 4.5.0, 4.5.0
```

I was able to run a similar setup with terraform version 3.74 in my main manifest before but I upgraded some modules and as far as I can see the current min version is 4.5.0 so I switched to that.
I'm unsure if the current problem is caused by the

```
  ~> 3.69
```

from one of my included modules or if I'm missing something else.

My current provider configuration is the following:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I found some modules that use the ~> operator for their examples like:

```
./.terraform/modules/kubernetes_addon.velero_thanos_bucket/examples/notification/versions.tf:      version = "~> 3.69"
./.terraform/modules/kubernetes_addon.velero_thanos_bucket/examples/object/versions.tf:      version = "~> 3.69"
./.terraform/modules/s3_bucket_for_logs/examples/complete-legacy/versions.tf:      version = "~> 3.69.0"
```

I'm already using the newest version of those modules and they have been working when I was enforcing version 3.74 in the `required_providers` previously.

Comment: You need to add the entire `required_providers` block to the question. But it seems you have a plethora of provider versions and it's confusing Terraform as there is no single version that will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: I put the information in the post.

Comment: Can you show the `versions.tf` which has the `3.69` in it, because right now it's really not clear what might the problem be.

Comment: You can run `terraform providers` to get some more detail about which of the modules in your configuration specified which version constraints, in case you want to change one or more of them to not conflict with the others.

Answer (score 2):

[~>](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/version-constraints#-3) is a very stringent constraint, and so is `=` as you require above.

> = (or no operator): Allows only one exact version number. Cannot be combined with other conditions.

> ~>: Allows only the rightmost version component to increment. For example, to allow new patch releases within a specific minor release, use the full version number: ~> 1.0.4 will allow installation of 1.0.5 and 1.0.10 but not 1.1.0. This is usually called the pessimistic constraint operator.

Something can't both be exactly 4.5.0 and greater than 3.69 but less than 4.0.